# typo3 website move to other domain - need help step by step

Tags: url, dns, typo3

I just got a typo3 website and need to transfer to an other domain.
Is it enough to copy all the folders (except typo3temp?) to the new place? 
First I just changed baseurl in ts but it didn't do anything..
Should I do anything with the database when it still on the same server?

Comment: "It didn't do anything"? Please clarify. What error are you getting?

Comment: go to the install tool (not backend) and clear your cache.

Comment: You should post error if any or describe more so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

In case your question is about "cloning" a complete TYPO3-system an rsync/copy of the whole folder (yes including typo3temp) is the best idea, as this works on all versions, everything else (like excluding typo3temp) depends a whole lot on your TYPO3 expertise to resolve. The database needs to be copied as well. If you need to change db-name or db-credentials on the new system you need to change  them in

```
typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php
```

As soon as you have done this Install Tool and Backend should work: At first try the Install Tool:
https://my.new.domain/typo3/install/

If that doesn't work your problem is with the webserver configuration or dns.

If that works (and the reports there show no errors), try the Backend:
https://my.new.domain/typo3/

In case your question is about which changes are necessary to your TYPO3-installation if domain changes and the web server itself is configured correctly, then there are probably two things you need to change, in order to make the frontend work (although both cases might be omitted, depending on your configuration):

- sys_template record, if any of those use absRefPrefix or baseurl. If you have access to the MySQL-Database a

  ```
  SELECT pid FROM sys_template WHERE config LIKE "%baseurl%" OR "%absRefPrefix";
  ```

  might help finding the template, however these template configuration might also be stored in files (typically in fileadmin/templates/**)
- sys_domain records, a MySQL

  ```
  SELECT pid FROM sys_domain;
  ```

  might uncover where those are stored

However these changes are only necessary to enable the frontend to work.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer. I have copied the whole page to an other domain, but the server is the same so I didn't do anything changes with the database. The old one was a testing page under a subfolder of an other domain. I just copied all of the contents with ftp. I didn't do anything with install tool because I didn't changed the database and localconf.php. When I log in to the new backend, It is just the same, like with the old one. I have changed baseurl in constants.ts and that's all. But my links are not correct, after one click I'm landing on the old page...

Comment: Please update your question with following details: do you have EXT:cooluri or EXT:realurl installed, which version of TYPO3 are you using.

Nevertheless: probably a sys_domain record, setup.ts or cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a domain record in the backend. And while you don't need the content of the typo3temp folder, make sure the folder actually exists.

Answer (score -1):

When you go to the new domain name in your browser, what happens?

Do you get redirected to the old domain?  If so, maybe there is an  .htaccess redirect happening.

Do you get to the new domain, but if you click on a link end up on the old one?

Do you get an error?  If so, what is the error?

Does something else happen?

Comment: For the fisrt time it seemed everything is fine, but after the first click I am landing on the old page. I have changed baseURL for the new one, I have wrote the absRefPrefix = / line but it also doesn't help.